# How to split string which is in the form an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a string in the form of an array.
Like..,
"["123", "456", "789"]"; "["abc", "xyz"]"
I want to access the elements inside that is; "123", "456"...
How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Make sure your have added the correct input and output to the question. JSON is not valid.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go;

```js
let str = "['123', '456', '789']"

let res = str.slice(str.indexOf('[') + 1, str.length - 1)

let result = res.split(', ')

let req = []

result.map(item => {
let i = item.replace(/'/g, '')
req.push(i)
}) 

console.log(req)
```

Nothing special here. Used the in-built function `slice` to get the slice of the given string. Slice takes two args , starting index and end index. starting index character is included in the string, that is why, i am adding 1 to it to exclude '['. End index is excluded.

Then i splited the result at `,`  , removed single quotes from every element. that is it.