# How to get all the multiple quoted text inside a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, double-quotes

I have a variable `var s = '["hi","hello","What\'s new"]';` in **string** format.
How do i get the values `hi` `hello` `What's new` separately.

Also the values in the variable **s** is dynamic, some times it maybe `var s = '["wow","okay"]';` or any values.

*Can someone help me with this?*

Comment: what do you mean by separately?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` to get an array from `s`, then use a `for` loop to iterate it and get the items - your question looks similar to this question: [How to split string which is in the form an array using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68507420)

Comment: First of all, there is an error in this code ```var s = '["hi","hello","What's new"]'``` you need to write ```var s = '["hi","hello","What\'s new"]'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in this code `var s = '["hi","hello","What's new"]'` you need to write `var s = '["hi","hello","What\'s new"]'` otherwise it will give you this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

If you are looking for the output like this:

> ["hi","hello","What's new"]

Then this is the solution:

```js
var s = '["hi","hello","What\'s new"]'
console.log(JSON.parse(s))
```